# if I want to import types of ts-morph, how could I know all the types of it by this built code(only dist file)?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I installed ts-morph library in my project.

I see the code structure of it.

```
node_modules/
  ts-morph/
    dist/
      ts-morph.js
    lib/
      ts-morph.d.ts
```

there I have several questions about it.

1.when we use it in VSCode, how could IDE be associated with `ts-morph.d.ts`?

2.and if I want to import types of ts-morph, how could I know all the types of it by this built code(only dist file)?